# Extract part of a string which start with a certain word in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following string

```
"sis":4,"sct":15,"ssu":"89c4eef0-3a0d-47ae-a97f-42adafa7cf8f","ssv":384,"siw":96554,"scx":1049,
```

I need to get string after "ssu":" the Result should be 89c4eef0-3a0d-47ae-a97f-42adafa7cf8f. How do I do it in Javascript but very simple? I am thinking to collect 36 character after "ssu":".

Comment: Are you trying to extract a value from json data?

Comment: This looks a lot like JSON, so I would simply remove the trailing comma, surround the string with curly brackets and use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: If it is a string you can use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the following regular expression:

```
/\"ssu\":\"([\w-]+)\"/
```

This pattern basically means:

1. > \"ssu\":\" , start searching from the first instance of "ssu":"
2. > ([\w-]+) , collect a "group" of one or more alphanumeric characters \w and hypens -
3. > \", look for a " at the end of the group

Using a group allows you to extract a portion of the matched pattern via the  [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method that is of interest to you which in your case is the guid that corresponds to `([\w-]+)`

A working example of this would be:

```js
const str = `"sis":4,"sct":15,"ssu":"89c4eef0-3a0d-47ae-a97f-42adafa7cf8f","ssv":384,"siw":96554,"scx":1049,`

const value = str.match(/\"ssu\":\"([\w-]+)\"/)[1]

console.log(value);
```

#### Update: Extract multiple groupings that occour in string

To extract values for multiple occurances of the "ssu" key in your input string, you could use the [`String#matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) method to achieve that as shown:

```js
const str = `"sis":4,"sct":15,"ssu":"89c4eef0-3a0d-47ae-a97f-42adafa7cf8f","ssv":384,"siw":96554,"scx":1049,"ssu":"value-of-second-ssu","ssu":"value-of-third-ssu"`;

const values = 
    /* Obtain array of matches for pattern */
    [...str.matchAll(/\"ssu\":\"([\w-]+)\"/g)]
    /* Extract only the value from pattern group */
    .map(([,value]) => value);

console.log(values);
```

Note that for this to work as expected, the `/g` flag must be added to the end of the original pattern. Hope that helps!

Comment: In the case I have two or more ssu parameter in the string how can I extract the second one?

Comment: @MSSHD just updated answer with a demo on how to achieve that - does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You could build a valid [JSON](https://json.org/) string and parse it and get the wanted property `ssu`.

```js
var string = '"sis":4,"sct":15,"ssu":"89c4eef0-3a0d-47ae-a97f-42adafa7cf8f","ssv":384,"siw":96554,"scx":1049,',
    object = JSON.parse(`{${string.slice(0, -1)}}`), // slice for removing the last comma
    ssu = object.ssu;

console.log(ssu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regExp: `/(?!"ssu":")(\w+-)+\w+/`

```js
const str = '"sis":4,"sct":15,"ssu":"89c4eef0-3a0d-47ae-a97f-42adafa7cf8f","ssv":384,"siw":96554,"scx":1049,';

const re = /(?!"ssu":")(\w+-)+\w+/;

const res = str.match(re)[0];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions.

```
var str = '"sis":4,"sct":15,"ssu":"89c4eef0-3a0d-47ae-a97f-42adafa7cf8f","ssv":384,"siw":96554,"scx":1049,'

var minhaRE = new RegExp("[a-z|0-9]*-[a-z|0-9|-]*");
minhaRE.exec(str)
```

OutPut: Array [ "89c4eef0-3a0d-47ae-a97f-42adafa7cf8f" ]

Answer (score 0):

Looks almost like a JSON string.

So with a small change it can be parsed to an object.

```
var str = '"sis":4,"sct":15,"ssu":"89c4eef0-3a0d-47ae-a97f-42adafa7cf8f","ssv":384,"siw":96554,"scx":1049, ';

var obj = JSON.parse('{'+str.replace(/[, ]+$/,'')+'}');

console.log(obj.ssu)
```